# How to overload the stringstream insertion operator?

Tags: c++

I would like to parse a comma-separated-value string with a stringstream without having to call stringstream::ignore() for each value.

```
std::string csvString = "1,2,3,4";
int i1, i2;
std::stringstream ss(csvString);
ss >> i1;
ss >> i2;
if (ss.fail())
   throw "failed!"
```

Most tutorials about overloading the insertion operator use a user defined type as the the right hand operand. I have seen a few other examples. I suppose the solution would look something like this:

```
class ParserStream
{
private:
    std::stringstream & m_ss;
public:
    ParserStream(std::stringstream & ss): m_ss(ss){} 

    template<typename T>
    ParserStream & operator>>(T val)
    {
        m_ss >> val;
        m_ss.ignore();
        return *this;
    }    
};
```

It doesn't work. How could it work?

Comment: "I would like to parse a comma-separated-value string with a stringstream without having to call stringstream::ignore() for each value" You can do that with the `std::getline` overload that takes a separator: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline. Is there anything else I'm misunderstanding in your question?

Comment: Maybe define a custom manipulator?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "It doesn't work". Your code seems fine, except you're not taking `val` by reference.

Comment: @cigien You are right: the RHS was not being passed as a reference. That was the problem. It works with that change. If you want to create an answer, I will mark the post as answered.

Comment: @anthonyvd I have a hundred column object in a comma-separated-value string. The code is much easier to look at if each line inserts to 1 variable, without the lines having other calls between them. Your solution would write the value to a string first and require subsequent commands.

Comment: @rur2641 Your call! I'd personally find the reader not having to track down a custom `stringstream` wrapper more readable about 90% of the time, but you definitely know your codebase and coworkers better than I do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cigien said in the comments, the problem was that the right hand side parameter is not passed by reference. The following code works correctly:

```
template<typename T>
ParserStream & operator>>(T & val)
{
    m_ss >> val;
    m_ss.ignore();
    return *this;
}
```